# How to determine which tmpfs ran out of space overnight

Tags: linux, tmpfs

I have a process that is using tmpfs and I need to know, out of many tmpfs, which one is getting full.
Is there a way to do that after a nightly process has failed due to 'out of memory' errors?

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                   4G     0    4G   0% /dev
tmpfs                      4G     0    4G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      4G     0    4G   0% /run
tmpfs                      4G     0    4G   0% /run/user/677
```

Comment: When you are running the process, you can do `lsof -p <pid>` and see what the process touches. BTW, does the process run with root privileges? If not, then only the last one is a possibility.

Comment: @NickD  Good point.  It is not a process that runs with 'root' privileges, or so I have been told by the application developers.  It runs in the very early morning hours.

Answer (score 0):

After getting more physical memory, changed the following variable in the `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file to the value below:

```
RuntimeDirectorySize=50%
```

Rebooted and issue resolved.

Prior to this, my `RuntimeDirectorySize` variable was commented out, therefore it defaulted to `10%`.